# Error after moving WordPress installation

Tags: errors, migration

I am trying to move a WordPress site to a new server, but I cannot get it up and running on my local server (running XAMPP).

The site is running perfectly fine, but when I download the files, export the database and then hook everything up on my local copy, I get the following error message:

```
Warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function 'twentyten_widgets_init' not found or invalid function name in /Users/Tim/Sites/coachhousetimbers.com.au/old/wp-includes/plugin.php on line 405
```

And the following when I try to access the site's dashboard:

```
Warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function 'twentyten_widgets_init' not found or invalid function name in /Users/Tim/Sites/coachhousetimbers.com.au/old/wp-includes/plugin.php on line 405
Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /Users/Tim/Sites/coachhousetimbers.com.au/old/wp-includes/plugin.php:405) in /Users/Tim/Sites/coachhousetimbers.com.au/old/wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 934
```

Any ideas and/or suggestions?

I have moved many WordPress websites in the past and this is the first time I've seen this error. I am running WordPress 3.2.1.

Thanks!

Comment: is your new site loading from `coachhousetimbers.com.au/old/` ? That's where WP is looking...

Comment: That's just where I'm trying to install the site locally.

Answer (score 1):

Is the site still working/displaying properly , other than this error on the front end?

It looks to me like your new hosting environment has warning and notice reporting ON.

Consider looking in your `wp-config.php` file for `WP_DEBUG` and make sure it's set to `false`.

Depending on how much control you have on your hosting environment, you should contact your hosting provider to adjust the PHP [`error_reporting`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) to only errors.

**EDIT:** I would first suggest going into your development location and  looking in your `wp-config.php` file for `WP_DEBUG` and make sure it's set to `true`.

The best way to avoid these warnings is to fix them at the source. It's probably a very simple fix - it looks like the function `twentyten_widgets_init` doesn't exist within your theme, which if you forked the twentyten theme instead of creating a [child theme](http://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes), is likely the case. You may have mistakenly renamed the function without addressing the hook where it's being attached.

Answer (score 0):

Try to run this search-replace script as it is able to do proper replaces inside serialized options: [Search Replace DB](https://github.com/interconnectit/Search-Replace-DB/).

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is install the [WP Migrate DB plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-migrate-db/) and add the new server path and site url before exporting the database.

Answer (score -2):

Here's the easy way to do it.

1. Copy all files to your new installation exactly in the order it was in the previous installation.
2. Download and install  [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/) if you don't already have it.
3. Export the db through your phpmyadmin and open the exported sql in notepad++ and press CTRL + H (find and replace dialog box).
4. a. In find, enter your localhost url, e.g. like `127.0.0.1/mywpinstallation` ( remember, no trailing slashes / "http://"   or you get everything messed up).

   b. In replace, enter the production url, e.g. `myproductionsite.com` ( again, no trailing slashes or "http://").

Hit replace all.

1. Now import the modified sql to your production database, change the db details in wp-config.php and then login to your wp-admin with the same credentials you used to have in localhost.
2. Go to Settings -> permalink and choose a permalink scheme and save ( do it even if you already have a permalink scheme set.Doing this will rewrite the htaccess for you).

If you have done everything correctly, you should now have a perfectly working production site. Be sure to take additional measures for securing your site. I am not going to discuss that over here.

Comment: lol that was my last answer in stackexchange wordpress. I swear I will be the best leech ever. -1 for answering it correctly? Lawl.

Comment: Most would not consider this a "correct" answer.  You have the find and replace backward, and you could corrupt serialized data with a simple text S&R operation.  I myself have done virtually what you describe successfully, only when I know there isn't any serialized data to worry about.